# Karma error - Unknown provider: $$asyncCallbackProvider

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Trying to run my karma test through grunt but getting an error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMock due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$asyncCallbackProvider
```

I removed 'ngAnimate' but does not resolve it. How can I run the grunt karma test without this error?

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem just now, and fixed it by making sure the version of my angular-mock dependancy was the same as that angular.

You can do this in your bower.json file (change "angular-mocks": "~1.3.0" to "angular-mocks": "^1.3.0" or a specific version).

Comment: Same problem here and checked my versions. All of them macth ( 1.5.8), but problem still exists. Any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

While I have no doubt that 3sdmx's answer would work, I just ran an NPM update and that worked. Thought I should mention that so that people aren't maintaining their .json files so closely.

Answer (score 0):

You should add all the angular dependencies that you used in your project to your **karma.conf.js** file.
It seems like you need to add ngMock to your karma file, like the example below :

```
    files: [
         '*/**/angula-ngMock.js'
    ],
```