# How to configure this karma test?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to unit test my filter , this is the js:

```
app.filter('dateRange', function() {
  return function(input,dateFrom,dateTo) {
      return _.filter(input, function(d) {
         var result= Date.parse(d.settlementDate) >= Date.parse(dateFrom) && Date.parse(d.settlementDate) <= Date.parse(dateTo)
          return result;
      });
  }
});
```

I am using underscore.js in this one. This is the files section of karma.conf:

```
 files: [

            'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
            'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
            'bower_components/angular-smart-table/dist/smart-table.min.js',
            'bower_components/underscore/underscore.js',
            'app/modules/**/*.js',
            'app/modules/app.js',
            //'../app/scripts_old/**/*.js',
            //  'test/mock/**/*.js',
            'test/spec/**/*.spec.js'
        ],
```

This is the spec:

```
'use strict';

describe('Filter: daterange', function () {

    var $filter;
    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myModule');
    });

    beforeEach( inject(function (_$filter_) {
        $filter = _$filter_;
    }));

    it('should be in the range',function(){
        expect($filter('dateRange')('08/10/2015','08/01/2015','08/30/2015')).toBeTruthy;
    });

});
```

bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "angularmain-fork",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.0",
    "json3": "^3.3.0",
    "es5-shim": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "underscore": "~1.8.3",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.3",
    "angular-smart-table": "~2.1.2",
    "moment": "~2.10.6",
    "angular-animate": "~1.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.0",
    "angular-smart-table": "~2.1.2"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Why am I getting this error?:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMock due to:
>
> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$asyncCallbackProvider

Comment: Can you make sure the version of angular and angular-mocks is the same ?

Comment: according to the bower.json the versions are the same.

Comment: error is not caused by your filter code.Any other module got failed.Can you please show how you have declared your main module "app"

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves your problem: [Answer to same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31886983/515954)

I've just tried it (just putting `^` in the beginning of the version number) and it solved my problem.