# Karma testing Angular 1.5 . Weird $$asyncCallback error

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

So, I'm Pretty new to karma+jasmine testing. Read some tutorials and finally managed to set up the testing environment.

First I tried to test some simple directive. and ended (after much googling, trial and error,etc) leaving it for later after a lot of

```
 [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$asyncCallbackProvider
```

Now, Trying to test a simple service (factory). I find the **same error**.
It happens no matter what I try

- Mocking a module
- Using the real one

Some  details:

.- Yes, I checked that my angular.js and angular-mocks.js versions match. ( as suggested [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832947/karma-error-unknown-provider-asynccallbackprovider))

**bower.json (excerpt)**

```
"dependencies": {
"angular": "^1.5.8",
"angular-route": "^1.5.8",
"angular-sanitize": "^1.5.8",
"angular-mocks": "^1.5.8",
"angular-moment": "^1.0.0",
"angular-animate": "^1.5.8",
},
```

I've build a Plunkr with all related files [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mViugZTTGrcyB97NLr8c)

I tried different approximations found  out there. But I always end at same point.

It's an error of my environment ( and /or my understanding ) ?
It's a know Bug ( It doesn't seem so, but I'm not an expert) ?
Any idea on how to correct it, workaround ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Your plunkr doesn't have any of those files.

Comment: .@jb-nizet Sorry. URL for Plunkr corrected. it should be working now